# How to create attribute based xml in c#

Tags: c#, sql, xml

How to create attribute based xml in c# from stored procedure returning result

Stored Procedure contains:

```
Select * from Patients
```

I want XML:

```
<Patient patientid =”1”  domainid =”1” domainname =” Test Domain”/>
```

I am getting this:

```
<Patient>
    <patientid>1</patientid>
    <domainid>1</domainid>
    <domainname>Test Domain</domainname>
  </Patient>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to change your proc to return an xml string generated by `FOR XML AUTO`

```
Select * 
FROM  Patients AS Patient
FOR XML AUTO;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94068/3)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are getting result as `DataSet` from Stored Procedure.

You can set`ColumnMapping`, and then write to xml. .

```
DataTable dt ; // Patients information retrieved from db.

foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    column.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
}

dt.WriteXml(@"C:\Patients.xml");
```

Hope this helps !!